# Python sort a list of lists by occurrence and reversed order

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following list

```
list_55 = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,4],[5,6],[4,3],[1,2],[1,2],[6,5],[6,5]]
```

I want to sort this list like this. So that the list sorts in an order with descending occurrence and with their reversed list. For example:

```
[1,2],[1,2],[1,2] followed by [2,1]
[6,5],[6,5] followed by [5,6]
[4,3] followed by [3,4] The order of this last one doesn't matter.
```

output:

```
[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[2,1],[6,5],[6,5],[5,6],[4,3],[3,4]]
```

I tried:

```
sorted(list_55, key=list_55.count, reverse=True)
```

which gives:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [6, 5], [6, 5], [2, 1], [3, 4], [5, 6], [4, 3]]
```

and

```
sorted(list_55,reverse=True)
```

gives:

```
[[6, 5], [6, 5], [5, 6], [4, 3], [3, 4], [2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

I want a combination of these two. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(
    sorted(
        list_55,
        key=lambda l: (
            list_55.count(l) + list_55.count(l[::-1]),
            list_55.count(l),
        ),
        reverse=True,
    )
)
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1], [6, 5], [6, 5], [5, 6], [3, 4], [4, 3]]
```

---

A little bit more performant solution using `:=`:

```py
print(
    sorted(
        list_55,
        key=lambda l: (
            (cnt := list_55.count(l)) + list_55.count(l[::-1]),
            cnt,
        ),
        reverse=True,
    )
)
```

---

For more performance a version with `functools.lru_cache`:

```py
from timeit import timeit
from functools import lru_cache
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

list_55 = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [4, 3],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [6, 5],
    [6, 5],
]


def fn1(lst):
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def key_fn(l):
        cnt = lst.count(l)
        return cnt + lst.count(l[::-1]), cnt

    lst[:] = map(tuple, lst)

    return sorted(
        lst,
        key=key_fn,
        reverse=True,
    )


def fn2(l):
    dct = defaultdict(Counter)
    for lst in l:
        dct[frozenset(lst)].update({tuple(lst): 1})

    # counters_sorted = sorted(
    #     dct.values(), key=lambda c: c.total(), reverse=True
    # )
    counters_sorted = sorted(
        dct.values(), key=lambda c: sum(c.values()), reverse=True
    )  # for python < 3.10

    return [
        tup
        for counter in counters_sorted
        for tup, n in counter.most_common()
        for _ in range(n)
    ]


t1 = timeit(
    "fn1(lst)", setup="lst = list_55 * 1000", number=1, globals=globals()
)

t2 = timeit(
    "fn2(lst)", setup="lst = list_55 * 1000", number=1, globals=globals()
)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints (AMD 3700x/Python 3.9):

```
0.0037845000624656677
0.011112367967143655
```

Comment: Thank you! So first sort by the total occurrence of the list and its reversal and then within the first sorting sort by the number of the most frequent list.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `collections.Counter`, which I guess is more efficient when the input list is long:

```py
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

list_55 = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,4],[5,6],[4,3],[1,2],[1,2],[6,5],[6,5]]

dct = defaultdict(Counter)
for lst in list_55:
    dct[frozenset(lst)].update({tuple(lst): 1})

counters_sorted = sorted(dct.values(), key=lambda c: c.total(), reverse=True)
# counters_sorted = sorted(dct.values(), key=lambda c: sum(c.values()), reverse=True) # for python < 3.10

output = [tup for counter in counters_sorted
              for tup, n in counter.most_common()
              for _ in range(n)]

print(output)
# [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (6, 5), (6, 5), (5, 6), (3, 4), (4, 3)]
```

Comment: Can you make some benchmark (for various lengths of lists?) I've already upvoted you but I'm really curious :)

Comment: I've added version with `functools.lru_cache` for more performance.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks! I've learned from your post!